# Android: Change Emulator's SD Card

Tags: android

Is it possible to make changes to the sdcard being used in an Android Emulator? For instance, I'd like to change the size of the SD card being used in the emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the avd directory, which is in the following location:

> Windows:
>   %userprofile%.android\avd\<avd-name-here>

There is a file called sdcard.img. you can replace that with the new image file.

you can create a new sdcard image file by using `mksdcard` in the android-sdk/tools

> usage: mksdcard [-l label] <size> <file>

Comment: Thanks for the Info Ryan. After a little investigating, I've found that you can't resize existing virtual SD cards, so your solution is the next best thing, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do this is to open the AVD manager create a new Android Virtual Device with a bigger/smaller SD card size. AFAIK, there's not a way to change the size of a device after it's been created - at least, not through Eclipse.